# iOS PWA translucent status bar is solid black, does not show scrolling content

Tags: html, ios, safari, frontend, progressive-web-apps

I'd like my website on iOS to scroll into the status bar but so far it's only solid black.

Here's my head setup:

```
<style>
    body {
        background-color: #000000;
    }
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
```

Am I missing something? I'd like to have the content scroll through the translucent status bar like it does in safari on desktop. Thanks!